# MVC Javascript PartialView

Tags: javascript

I have an Index.cshtml with a left-side menu items. Based on the menu item clicked, partial views are rendered in the left panel. Each partial view is rendered with its own model.

In one of my partial views, I am trying to populate some text boxes with model's values in my JavaScript as textBoxName.SetText(@Html.Raw(@Model.textValue)). The javascript code from my partial view is not included when the page is rendered. 
How do I include JavaScript code in my partial view?

Thank you
NH

Comment: you don't. I assume you're loading the partials via ajax? Scripts fetched by ajax calls which return a mix of HTML and script are generally not rendered or executed - it's a security thing, I think. Any script which the partial might rely on needs to be included in the main page (either directly or as a separate .js file)

Comment: I am trying to do some client side scripting where my javascript has several methods that access each different model that is returned to the partial view. If I cannot execute javascript in my partial view, is there a way to access the model from javascript. One way that comes to my mind is to store the models in separate hidden elements and access them in the main page's script section. But, I am not sure how to go about accessing model in javascript. Any idea is helpful.

Comment: Yes that's exactly how you'd have to do it. The model is a server side concept and never accessible directly from script. What you're trying to do now is inject model data directly into a script so the browser treats it as a hard coded value in the finished script. What you'll have to do instead is render the model data into hidden DOM elements and have the script fetch the data from those elements when needed

Comment: I am trying to access the entire model(from hidden field) as                 
 var _modelObj = document.getElementById("nameOfHiddenField").value                                            How do I access individual property of the model? Also, some of my models have lists. I am not sure how to access these in my javascript. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what you put in your hidden field, or in what format, so it's difficult to say. Did you use JSON? I wasn't thinking you'd put the whole thing into one field, rather that you'd create an element for each field that you need to access. But if you need access to the whole model from script, or don't know in advance what you need to access, then maybe you're better writing it to the field as JSON. It's bit unusual for a script to want to access the whole model as an object, normally the script is just used to work on the HTML

Comment: I have multiple JSON objects returned by the server. Ideal situation would be if I could store these JSON objects in hidden fields and then parse them in client side javascript method, then I could dynamically update form controls based on button and menu clicks.